# How to resolve an exception for exceeding maxJsonLength in javaScriptSerializer in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to POST a Json string in my controller which contains 9K rows and I am using TryUpdateModel to update the model with the Json string but getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException exception: Error during serialization or
>   deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the
>   string exceeds the value

I am using MVC 3. I've tried to configure the max length for json requests in my web.config file but still not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you using Json.Net?

Comment: No I am not using Json.net, I have to do without using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the maxJsonLength for JavaScriptSerializer in web.config checking this nuances:

- maxJsonLength represents the maximum number of UTF-8 characters in the string.
- maxJsonLength is int32 so max value is +2.147.483.647

i.e.: (change assembly versions and PublicKeyToken as needed)

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

    <configuration>
      <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000"/> 
          </webServices>
        </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>
    </configuration>
```

You can also use a custom converter:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50"/>
          <converters>
            <add name="MyCustomConverter" 
              type="MyCompany.ConvertersNameSpace.MyTypeConverter"/>
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

I recomend you [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil)

More documentation in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb763183(v=vs.100))

If you are using JavascriptSerializer by hand web.config has no effect. You have to set maxJsonLength into the instance you created:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
```

If nothing works maybe you can use your own ValueProviderFactory:

https://translate.google.es/translate?hl=es&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.naver.com%2Ftechshare%2F100145191355

Comment: I've set the max value 2.147.483.647 but still not working.

Comment: What is the size of your 9K rows?

Comment: The size of the Json is 6.12 MB

Comment: Hi @jlvaquero, Thanks a lot for your help. The issue has been resolved after using custom ValueProviderFactory.

Comment: @AritraNandy Then do not forget to upvote and acept the answer to help others find the solution fast.